# Iconv convert from UTF-8 to Windows-1250 doesn't work

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've always had problems with iconv. Now I must convert string to Windows-1250 and this doesn't seems to work:

```
$string = "ľaľa ho papľuha, ogrcal mi krpce!";
echo $string . ' ( ' . mb_detect_encoding($string) . ' ) <br>';
$string_encoded = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $string ), 'Windows-1250//TRANSLIT', $string );
echo $string_encoded . ' ( ' . mb_detect_encoding($string_encoded) . ' ) <br>';
$string_encoded = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'Windows-1250' );
echo $string_encoded . ' ( ' . mb_detect_encoding($string_encoded) . ' ) <br>';
```

The three echos above output exactly this:

```
ľaľa ho papľuha, ogrcal mi krpce! ( UTF-8 )
�a�a ho pap�uha, ogrcal mi krpce! ( ) 
mb_convert_encoding() Unknown encoding &quot;Windows-1250&quot; ( ASCII )
```

Since I've always seen this diamond question marks I wonder if this PHP function works at all. How can I convert UTF-8 to Windows-1250?

- The file was saved in notepad+ in UTF-8
- Also I've tried `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1250');` and `setLocale()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The � character is an indication that your text is being interpreted as UTF-8, but at this point an invalid byte sequence was encountered. Meaning, you're not serving UTF-8, yet the client is reading it as UTF-8. Which would imply that `iconv` is working just fine and whoever is reading the result just didn't get the message that it should be interpreting it as Windows-1250.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: Yes you were right. The encoding was sent as windows-1250 but browser didn't display it right

Answer (score 11):

I have experienced a similar issue. While reading CSV file, word "Česká republika" was read as "Èeská republika".

This solved it for me:

```
iconv( "Windows-1250", "UTF-8", ($string));
```

Comment: yeah, it works for me too. My mistake was a reversed order of src encoding to destination

Answer (score 2):

Is old post but you can convert UTF-8 to Windows-1252 and you will have same effect:

```
$str = "ľaľa ho papľuha, ogrcal mi krpce!"
$str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8" );
```

but if you realy need Windows-1250 you can use [THIS SOLUTION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#112547) and adapt to your need.

Comment: Great $str example :D

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is `iconv( "UTF-8", "Windows-1250", $string );`

Comment: You should comment or make a suggested edit for the answer you wish to correct, not post a new answer.

Comment: @Das_Geek We do not suggest edits to suggest more correct answer. Such edits are usually rejected. Provide an alternative solution instead. In this case I think Pavel has suggested a better answer, which is perfectly acceptable, whether it is correct or not is another thing.